# How do I to adjust the identation of any web site

Tags: html, css

How to ensure that the text does not exceed the gray border, and there is no scroll bar?
**Edit** I think that the problem is comming from the width of `<td class="message">`. i've also updated the HTML and CSS code.

[image]

Here is the code of that area

**HTML**

```
<div class="liste_posts">
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="message">
              <div class="topic_div">Si vous êtes sur cette page, c'est parce que vous avez décidé de laisser tomber phpbb, ou autre, pour vous lancer dans l'aventure qu'est la création d'un forum. Et ça tombe bien, parce que justement, ici on va voir comment faire ça Smiley. Il faut, avant de commencer, que vous sachiez que je vais montrer comment réaliser une base que vous pourrez ensuite faire évoluer comme bon vous semblera.</div>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.message{
background-color: rgb(244, 238, 250);
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.topic_div p {
word-break: break-all;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give it a defined width

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two different divs, one for the left side and one for the right side. Write text inside the left one.
Hopefully that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width of the box using the `max-width` and `min-width` css properties
I just read the answer below me, this would be an extension of that

Comment: @Josh - You probably want to avoid using references like "the post above/below" on SO. As votes come in they change the order and posts with the same score are loaded in a random order. Best to say "the post by X" to avoid confusion.